# Problem requiring the RMagick gem with Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rmagick

I installed RMagick on a Windows system with no apparent problems, but I'm having problems actually using it. In particular:

```
C:\Users\dancrumb> ruby -rubygems -rRMagick -e "puts Magick::Long_version"
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:900:in `report_activate_error':
RubyGem version error: rmagick(2.12.0 not >= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:212:in `rescue in try_activate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
```

The main sticking block is the seemingly illogical error message: `RubyGem version error: rmagick(2.12.0 not >= 0)`. Unless I'm missing something, 2.12.0 is most definitely greater than 0.

Some useful information:

```
C:\Users\dancrumb>gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-12-25 patchlevel 136) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby192/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - C:/Users/dancrumb/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/

C:\Users\dancrumb>dir \Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems
 Volume in drive C is TI106036W0F
 Volume Serial Number is 4432-A499

 Directory of C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems

...
03/26/2011  01:34 PM    <DIR>          rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32
...
03/20/2011  08:06 PM    <DIR>          rubygems-update-1.6.2
...
```

The supplied README file and the forums associated with RMagick don't afford any insight.

It gets weirder:

```
C:\Users\dancrumb>ruby -rubygems -e "gem 'rmagick', '2.12.0'; puts Magick::Long_
version"
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:900:in `report_activate_error':
RubyGem version error: rmagick(2.12.0 not = 2.12.0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1276:in `gem'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

As well as the specific question on RMagick, can anyone provide me with a sensible interpretation of the version error... it seems nuts to me, but maybe it is actually conveying something useful... just in a nutso way.

Comment: Generally the odd >=0 error relates to platform/architecture problems, from what I've seen. Are you working cross-platform? And, just to ask the dumb question, do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: @Clint. Not working cross platform... this is all local development on a Windows laptop, prior to being uploaded to a server.

Comment: @Clint. Not a dumb question. I *do* have ImageMagick installed, and it's the version of ImageMagick that came in the RMagick bundle `RMagick-2.12.0-ImageMagick-6.5.6-8-Q8.zip`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the very same problem in Ruby 1.8.7 as you with 1.9.1. This is a way I've resolved it:

1. Uninstall the rmagick gem if you have it (gem uninstall rmagick)
2. Download http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/64917/RMagick-2.12.0-ImageMagick-6.5.6-8-Q8.zip
3. Unpack the zip to separate folder (e.g. C:\temp\rmagick)
4. Install the ImageMagick-6.5.6-8-Q8-windows-dll.exe
5. Unpack the rmagick-2.12.0-x86-mswin32.gem to separate folder (e.g. C:\temp\rmagick\gem)
6. Extract the data.tar.gz to separate folder (e.g. C:\temp\rmagick\gem\data)
7. Open rmagick.gemspec and remove the line with s.platform = "mswin32"
8. Use "gem build rmagick.gemspec" to build the gem again (a "rmagick-2.12.0.gem" will be generated)
9. Use "gem install rmagick --local" to install it.

Answer (score 2):

Type the following:

```
ruby --version
```

If its output is something like

```
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]
```

it means the Ruby was built using mingw32, which was not supported by the RMagick.

Though README.html of RMagick-2.12.0-ImageMagick-6.5.6-8-Q8 package says

> Ruby 1.8.6, installed via the One-Click Installer.

in the prerequisites, [the latest One-Click Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/) is built using mingw32, and that causes the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code for rubygems, it looks like rmagick might be responding incorrectly to rubygems' queries about its version for some reason; not sure what.

When you don't supply a specific version number, rubygems will fall back on `>= 0` as its `version_requirements`.

Try this instead, to be more explicit, and so the versions match exactly:

```
ruby -rubygems -e "gem 'rmagick', '2.12.0'; puts Magick::Long_version"
```

Comment: Thanks Clint, I added more info to the question to show how that fails as well.

Comment: Ha, that's odd. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Perhaps try using gem bundler to lock in the gem version and manage that for you?