# Installe RMagick gem locally but unable to do the same using bundle install [windows 7(32 bit)]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was able to install the rmagick-2.6.0-x86-mswin32.gem gem in my windows 7 machine using gem install command and I got the following success messages:

```
 D:\dev>gem install rmagick-2.6.0
 Successfully installed rmagick-2.6.0-x86-mswin32
 1 gem installed
 Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.6.0-x86-mswin32...
 Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.6.0-x86-mswin32...
```

But when I try to install using bundle install (with the same version mentioned in the Gemfile) it throws the following error messages:

```
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
  .  D:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
 checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.2... yes
 checking for gcc... yes
 checking for Magick-config... no
 Can't install RMagick 2.6.0. Can't find Magick-config in D:\Ruby187\bin;D:\Ruby1
 ....
```

I already have ImageMagick installed and its paths included in the env vars, but the paths mentioned in the error message above seem to be different somehow(?!)

When i type rails -v now, I get the following message:

```
D:\dev>rails -v
←[31mCould not find gem 'rmagick (= 2.6.0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on
this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

1. Do i need to make any other changes/ setups to install this gem with my gemfile using bundle install?
2. Also I actually need an earlier gem '2.5.2' but the win32 specific version of that gem does not seem to available, is there any way to get it?

I need to do this development on windows for the moment so I can switch to any other OS for the moment. Also since this is a legacy app I am working on, I will need to stick with rmagick and can't switch to any other solution.

Env info:
Ruby: 1.8.7
Rails:

Please help!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey have you tried installing Devkit, for installing gems with native extensions on windows.

Try the steps in the following link, and check whether the Devkit has been installed in your path variable, try opening a new command shell and install the gems.

http://doelsengupta.blogspot.in/2010/10/unable-to-download-gem-with-native.html

all the best!!

Comment: Doel, I already have devkit but I uninstalled and re-installed and followed your instructions, with devkit in the path, am still facing this issue....:(

Answer (score 0):

I kept having this problem but was finally able to get around it using the following solution from @Martin Cohen - after modifying the gemspec file as he has suggested and rebuilding it, i was able to successfully install rmagick gem using bundle install...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5595274/1865578

cheers!